# Evolution calendar misbehaving (vertical space issue)

Tags: evolution

I have installed ubuntu 10.10 desktop on my 10' netbook (really dislike netbook remixes). Vertical space is a recurring issue, usually solved by maximising/fullscreening a window or, by setting visual effects to normal with the workspace switcher having an extra row (window across two workspaces).

Neither of these workarounds work for the calendar screen of Evolution. All the other screens act the way they are supposed to (mail, contacts, preferences, etc).

Whenever i try clicking anywhere on the calendar, including the min/max/close the entire window jumps up or down, making it impossible to select anything, forcing me to restart evolution just to get back to my inbox. I suspect the problem is in the dayview area.

So... how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have experienced this bug as well, ever since the early Maverick beta stages. 
This is an old bug (see [here on the Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/281217)), which isn't solved at the moment. A possible "workaround" is to launch Evolution in Express mode with `evolution --express`

Comment: Wow thats an old recurring bug. Will have to remember --express for when i find a calendar i like (any tips?). Back to TB for now then. Thanx.